# Photoshop - How to link layers visibility (not position)?

Tags: visibility, photoshop, layer

I have a photoshop file with a set of layers.

Is there a way that I can link "layer visibility" without having to click and unclick on the eye icon of each layer individually? For instance, I would like to set up instructions such as: 
  -If I click on the eye icon of layer A, activate the eye icon of layer B, AND C, AND D simultaneously...
  -activate the eye Icon of layer A OR B OR C... but don't allow to have more than one visible layer at the same time...

Grouping layers does not fit my purposes because I want to do that between layers that already belong to different groups.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't really programming related. I suggest trying [GraphicDesign](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), where you're likely to get good results.

Comment: Mmmm... I may have not explained myself sufficiently well then. I do believe it was related to programming. Anyway, I've found a fairly simple answer that allows me to connect data from VBA for excel into photoshop to creat thousands of user-defined combination of layers. Here is the link in case someone is interested :-) http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7416.html

Comment: I'm afraid so. Sorry, but from the context (references to Photoshop GUI elements only), I understood something else. Any sort of reference to scripting this, or maybe a tag(scripting,VB,jsx,etc.) would've been a handy hint to take. Glad you've managed to sort the issue and nice of you to document the solution.